# Bugsnag & Emberjs : application.lookup is not a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, deprecated, bugsnag

I'm trying to configure *Bugsnag* in my EmberJs(v2.12) application.

I am following this example: https://gist.github.com/ToddSmithSalter/23ad9ed91a693b498709

But I have an error in the browser telling that the lookup is not a function.

**app/initializer/bugsnag.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from '../config/environment';

export default {
  name: 'bugsnag',

  initialize: function(appInstance) {

      // appInstance.lookup is not a function
      var appController = appInstance.lookup('controller:application');
  }
};
```

Someone would have a way to access the application controller in an emberjs initializer?

Or maybe a better solution to install bugsnag on an Emberjs application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `instance-initializer` not `initializer`.
`Ember.Application` - does not have `lookup` method but `Ember.ApplicationInstance` has.

Reference:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/applications/applications-and-instances/
https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ApplicationInstance.html
https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html